# Sending data to another app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send Device_ID from one app to another. App_One stops working when i press button to send data.

And When I changed "action" from ACTION_SEND to ACTION_VIEW. App_ONE works fine but App_two don't show any result.

APP_ONE:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                String imei = "";
                if(tel.getImei() != null){
                    imei = tel.getImei();
                }else {
                    imei = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                }

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setText(imei);

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.putExtra("Data", imei);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

APP_TWO:

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="andoid.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

JAVA file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(i != null){
            String data = i.getString("Data");
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv.setText(data);
        }
    }}
```

Comment: If you know both apps why dont you use an Intent to start the Activity of another app!

Comment: i am using implicit intent ...

Comment: tell me one thing, i want to just show the string in textview. which action should i use ? ACTION_VIEW or something else

Comment: pllease add crashlog for App_one